# Number of post-hoc comparisons with emmeans

Tags: r, post-hoc, lsmeans

I would like to ask a question regarding a post-hoc analysis using R package emmeans.
I did a LME model analysis of a study of 2 groups x 4 measurement sessions. Now I am using emmeans for post-hoc comparisons. I am interested in finding out if the values within each of the groups differ between the sessions and also if both groups differ from each other at any session.
In emmeans, I used

emm1 <– emmeans(model, ~ Session | Group)

pairs(emm1, adjust = "mvt")

as well as

emm2 <– emmeans(model, ~ Group | Session)

pairs(emm1, adjust = "mvt")

For Session|Group it outputs a comparison of the sessions, for both groups separately. P values are corrected for 6 comparisons.
For Group|Session it outputs a comparison of both groups, separately for each session. Therefore, values are not corrected for multiple comparisons (as each session only consists of two means to compare, so the argument *adjust* is ignored). This normal behaviour is also illustrated on the vignette page for emmeans.

However, regarding my aim of the post-hoc analysis: should I force a multiple comparison correction? For example with the following:

summary(pairs(emm2), by = NULL, adjust = "mvt")

To me, applying a correction for 4 comparisons (groups at each session) sounds like it makes sense. What are your thoughts?
And if so, would I have to use the same argument (with by=NULL) for emm1, too? This would combine comparisons for both groups (12 tests). While it seems rational to treat both emm1 and emm2 equal from a mathematical point of view, I don't think it is necessary from a logical point of view...

Comment: I think you should be **consistent**. If you do separate adjustments of session comparisons for each group, then you should do separate adjustments comparisons of groups for each session, even though the latter is no adjustment.

Comment: Thanks! Any thoughts on whether it is better to force adjustments (use by=NULL) for both of them, or leave both of them as they are with fewer comparisons to correct for? (From a scientific/ logical point of view)

Comment: Depends on your discipline. But Id probably do separate adjustments for each group. Main thing is to clearly explain what you did.

Comment: Is there a way and/or would it make sense to view all the contrasts of emm1 and emm2 at once and correct for those 10 comparisons? I could of course use <<emm <– emmeans(model, ~ Group * Session)>> and then <<pairs(emm, adjust="mvt")>>, but this returns all 28 possible comparisons, mostly unnecessary ones like GroupA Session1 vs GroupB Session 3. Is it possible to get rid of those ones and only keep the ones I specified in emm1 and emm2 (=all within-group contrasts plus group comparisons for each session)?

Comment: You can use `rbind` and/or `[]` to combine or subset results and get all of the comparisons you want.

Comment: Much appreciated, that was exactely what I was looking for! Now that I know that's possible, I'm wondering if I should use that instead. Does is seem more reasonable to you to correct for all those 16 tests together, or to correct for Group|Session and Session|Group separately? I know that probably depends on the discipline and even more the reviewer, but I was wondering what your initial thought would be.

Comment: My preference is to treat each group as a separate family, which is what happens by default.